# Prove that $n! ≥ (⌈n/2⌉)^{⌈n/2⌉}$

Tags: algorithms, induction, factorial

Prove that : $n! ≥ (⌈n/2⌉)^{⌈n/2⌉}$

### Context

This is necessary for the proof that comparison-based sorting has a lower bound of $\mathcal{O}(n \cdot \log n)$

The proof goes like this:

1. There are $n!$ ways to permutate a sequence.
2. Comparison-based sorting needs to be able to distinguish all of those and it can only compare two elements at a time.
3. A binary tree on $n!$ elements has a depth of $\log(n!)$, hence comparison-based sorting has a lower computational complexity bound of $\mathcal{O}(n!)$

Now the question is if the following is true: $\mathcal{O}(n \cdot \log n) = \mathcal{O}(n!)$

If the inequality from above is true, then $\mathcal{O}(n \cdot \log n) \subseteq \mathcal{O}(n!)$ is true. As there are algorithms like Mergesort, we know that the other direction is true.

Comment: Hint: Count it. How many integers satisfies $k\ge n/2$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 4):

$$n! \geq n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) \cdots \lceil n/2 \rceil \geq (\lceil n/2 \rceil)^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}$$

Comment: That technically only works for $n$ even. There are  $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ terms in your right side.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $2a*(2a-1)*(2a-2)*...*a*k > a^a$ where $k>0$.